# Changing SpriteRenderer.color not working in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

So i am making a game and i have a building system for placing objects around.
i have a couple rules for the object to be placed down, the objects can be placed only if they arent colliding with other building game objects and when they are in range of a campfire (colliding with a range hitbox of a campfire)

if any of the 2 rules are broken the sprite should turn red
but if both are correct it should turn normal color,

the thing is that my code for it works as i have tested it with Debug.Log() but its the actual function that turns the sprite renderer a different color that doesnt work

here is my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BuildingPosSetup : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool IsPlaced;
    private Vector3 MPos;
    private bool IsObstructed;
    public IsPlacedTracker IsPlacedTrckr;
    private bool IsInrange;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        IsPlacedTrckr = (IsPlacedTracker)FindObjectOfType(typeof (IsPlacedTracker));
        IsPlacedTrckr.Num += 1;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        MPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

        if (IsPlaced == false)
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                if (IsObstructed == false)
                {
                    if (IsInrange)
                    {
                        IsPlaced = true;
                        IsPlacedTrckr.Num -= 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (IsPlaced == false)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(MPos.x, MPos.y, -6.667f);
        }


        if (IsObstructed == true || IsInrange == false)
        {
            if (IsPlaced == false)
            {
                gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color (0.66f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.66f); 
                Debug.Log("made red");
            }
        }

        else if (IsObstructed == false && IsInrange == true)
        {
            if (IsPlaced == false)
            {
                gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color (1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
                Debug.Log("made normal");
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.name == "Castle(Clone)" || col.name == "House(Clone)" || col.name == "CampFire(Clone)")
        {
            IsObstructed = true;
        }

        else if (col.name == "CampfireRange")
        {
            IsInrange = true;
        }
    }

    public void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.name == "Castle(Clone)" || col.name == "House(Clone)" || col.name == "CampFire(Clone)")
        {
            IsObstructed = false;
        }

        if (col.name == "CampfireRange")
        {
            IsInrange = false;
        }
    }
}
```

i tried storing the gameObject.GetComponent() in a different variable and then using that  variable but it doesnt change the color, i have seen many people struggle with the problem of colors not changing but their solution isnt in the function but the code;

Any help would greatly be appriciated!

Answer (score 0):

I created a gameObject, added your script (committed IsPlacedTracker because I don't have one) and rigidBody2D, and did something like "CampfireRange". My gameObject turned red. The color changed with twitching, so I also changed Update to FixedUpdate (because rigidBody2D was added). Try to do the same.

outside campfire range

[image]

inside

[image]

Comment: so the only thing i could really do was change the Update to FixedUpdate wich didnt change anything(i tried even tho i knew it wouldnt work at all), and now i am kinda lost because i dont know what else to try, But thanks for the help anyways!

Comment: Ok, I didn't express myself correctly, I thought you would repeat my steps to add components... 
Ok, could you share the settings of all the components of your object (which have a BuildingPosSetup script)? I mean inspector screenshots or link to the project.

Comment: or send here prefab file if you are not adding components to the object at runtime.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).